# Conditions inside of an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hello how can i add conditions inside an array ? Here are my if conditions

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)==FALSE)
{

}
if ($pass=='')
{

}  
if ($pass!=$confirm_pass)
{

}
```

and here is how my array should look after the 3 conditions from above

```
 $arr = array(
    'email'  => 'yes',
    'pass'  => 'yes',
    'confirm'  => 'yes',
    );
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: It's really a simple matter of creating an array and adding values. This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: `'email'  => ($pass=='' ? 'yes' : 'no'),`

Comment: It's not clear, what you want to do if the conditions evaluates as true and what to do when it evaluates as false

Comment: i send an json data as response and with ajax i display a message depends if they are true for false.  adeneo response is good, that's what i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
$arr = array();

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)==FALSE){
    $arr['email'] = 'Yes'; 
}
if ($pass==''){
    $arr['pass'] = 'Yes';
}  
if ($pass!=$confirm_pass) {
    $arr['confirm'] = 'Yes';
}

var_dump($arr );
```

Comment: thnx, that's working too, thnx